# String to timestamp in datastage 9.1.2

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-11g-r2, etl

Apologies for asking a question that I suppose is very basic. I'm just starting out with Streams.
I'm trying to read a sequential  files containing a timestamp field and a value field, like this:

150601172623+0530
150601172041+0530

I want add this value to oracle 11g database as a timestamps. Is there any way in datastage 9.1.2 for this conversation...?

Result should be like below

150601172623+0530 -> 2015-06-01 05:26:23 PM
150601172041+0530 -> 2015-06-01 05:20:41 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions214.htm#SQLRF06143) Function:

```
SELECT 
   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('150601172623+0530', 'RRMMDDHH24MISS+TZHTZM'), 
   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('150601172041+0530', 'RRMMDDHH24MISS+TZHTZM') 
FROM dual;


2015-06-01 17:26:23.000000000 +05:30   2015-06-01 17:20:41.000000000 +05:30
```

Comment: Thanx for this answer , Its correct , But I want output as a 2015-06-01 05:26:23 PM and 2015-06-01 05:20:41 PM for add to timestamp field in my database

Comment: You get a **TIMESTAMP**. If you want to convert it to a string surround it by `TO_CHAR(..., 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM')`. **But you should not store a timestamp as sting in a database**:

Comment: Thanx you so much

Comment: Is this a datastage function or oracle function. . ?

Comment: An Oracle function